# How do I forward or edit meetings to include new employees?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2007, exchange-2003

We've got many meetings, especially when people are on holiday and the working hours of people not working fulltime that involve all of our employees. Now whenever a new employee comes in, (s)he does not have all those meetings. How do I forward all those meetings? For emails I can use rules, but for meetings these are not available (and most meeting requests have been deleted).

Answer (score 0):

You can select the meeting from your calendar, and forward it from there.

If you open the calendar on Outlook 2010, then hold Ctrl and click on all the meetings you want to forward, the right click menu should have a forward option.